# flutter draw linechart with lineargradient

Tags: flutter, gradient, paint, linechart

I'm trying to draw a gradient in LineChart, but I had a problem.
I can't draw the gradation as I thought.
Please help me.

I Want..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adOET.png)

but chart is..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnkAl.png)

This is my Code.

```html
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    List<Offset> offsets = getCoordinates(points, size);
    drawText(canvas, offsets); 
    drawLines(canvas, size,  offsets);
    drawPoints(canvas, size, offsets); 
  }
  
  
    void drawLines(Canvas canvas, Size size, List<Offset> offsets) {
    final Gradient gradient = new RadialGradient(
      colors: <Color>[
        Colors.redAccent,
        Colors.blue,
        Colors.green,
        Colors.blueGrey,
        Colors.orange,
      ],
      stops: [
        0.0,
        0.25,
        0.5,
        0.75,
        1.0,
      ],
    );
    Rect rect = new Rect.fromCircle(
      center: new Offset(0.5, 0),
      radius: 300.0,
    );

    Paint paint = Paint()
      // ..color = lineColor
      ..strokeWidth = lineWidth
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..shader = gradient.createShader(rect);
    Path path = Path();

    double dx = offsets[0].dx;
    double dy = offsets[0].dy;

    path.moveTo(dx, dy);
    offsets.map((offset) => path.lineTo(offset.dx , offset.dy)).toList();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
  
    void drawPoints(Canvas canvas, Size size, List<Offset> offsets) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = pointColor
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = pointSize;

    canvas.drawPoints(PointMode.points, offsets, paint);
  }
```

Please, HELP ME

Answer (score 0):

You can install [syncfusion charts](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts) and use syncfusion line chart like this:

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Container(
                    child: SfCartesianChart(
                        primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
                        series: <ChartSeries>[
                            LineSeries<ChartData, String>(
                                dataSource: [
                                    ChartData('Jan', 35, Colors.red),
                                    ChartData('Feb', 28, Colors.green),
                                    ChartData('Mar', 34, Colors.blue),
                                    ChartData('Apr', 32, Colors.pink),
                                    ChartData('May', 40, Colors.black)
                                ],
                                // Bind the color for all the data points from the data source
                                pointColorMapper:(ChartData data, _) => data.color,
                                xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.x,
                                yValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.y
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }

    class ChartData {
        ChartData(this.x, this.y, this.color);
        final String x;
        final double y;
        final Color color;
    }
```